# Manage how user searches for app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app on Google Play titled:
ex. '**The Full App Name**' abbreviated '**TFAN**'

When searched for 'tfan', the app is displayed, but when searched for 'the full app name', there are no results.

This is a snippet from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_short_name" // TFAN
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Why is this happening?

If possible, can you let me know a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you include this in the manifest `android:label ="@string/app_name"`

Comment: The entire name of the app viz 'The Full App Name' will appear on the home screen of the phone thus resulting in the name being truncated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the overall rating of your app. The higher the rating, even if you type in a few words, the app shows in the list.

Hope this helps.